# Can I try to tell experienced users not to answer bad questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts

I have recently started using the website and I am trying to do my best with moderation. I flag questions very often, I edit posts when they can be improved, I have written a few of those "What have you tried?" comments and so on.

I know the topic has been discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions), and forgive me if this is not appropriate as a question, just let me know and I'll delete it.
I found that previous question very helpful, and it clarified some of my doubts. I'd like to ask a more specific question, which has only been touched by the previous one.

Often the people who answer bad posed questions are experienced users, with thousands and thousands of reputation. I understood these users are trusted and respected on the website. I often would like to comment on their answer saying "Why are you doing that?! This question should be closed not answered!" 
I have been told that when a question has accepted answers, it's more unlikely to be closed, even if the question itself, after edits and comments, is awful.

Would a comment like that be considered rude or somehow bad by the community? Most of all considering it would come from a relative new user?

P.S.: I preemptively apologize for possible horrible grammar mistakes.

Comment: You can try, and in fact I believe everyone should do it; but from past experiences, it's useless (a comment does nothing, while they gain reputation/satisfaction from answering these questions). Even making a comment to someone who answered a question and then voted to close it generally does nothing.  The answerer generally gets defensive or ignores the comment.

Comment: For what it's worth I think you are doing the right thing. Answering bad questions encourages more bad questions making the problem worse. But this is a divisive issue. Some think that it is a sign of *help vampires* and *rep wh@$£s* feeding each other. Others think they are still sitting in an exam, answering anything they can, and think this is natural. Yet others take the point of view that all the questions should be answered with all the skill and elegance we can muster. We also have somewhat experienced users who have simply seen even more experienced users do this, and just follow suit.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I imagined it won't help too much, but I don't mind tilting at windmills.

Comment: (cont'd) and there are also dedicated teachers, who simply want to try to educate. And those who want to show off. With all those (and more) different motives and points of view, it is difficult to find a middle ground.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the fact that they create a trend is one of the reasons I want to try to stop this from happening. Also, I think a real dedicate teacher doesn't belong to this category. Giving a ready-to-use solution to someone who doesn't even understand the question won't teach them much. Luckily (for me only) I have the most popular tags in the website (calculus and so on) blocked so I think I don't even see the worst instances of this trend.

Comment: @Silvia I think you need to open your mind to the fact that there are *many* views on how to best employ this platform to optimally share  mathematical knowledge. Be aware that some of the above comments make no sense given that many such users pay little attention to "rep" (indeed, they were just as prolific in prior non-rep forums such as sci.math). Alas, many users get so caught up in the gamification aspects of the platform that they fail to understand the true value of the site.

Comment: Silvia, what little I have seen of your approach to the site makes me nod in approval. I just want you to be aware of the variety of opinions about this. Also, norms of the site are under a continuous evolution. Robjohn tries to shed some light to that aspect (among other things) in his answer. Bill Dubuque offers another point of view. I agree with him that gamification aspects make the site worse than it could be in many ways  (we probably don't agree on exactly how it makes the site worse, but that's not really relevant here).

Comment: I have some sympathy for the answerers of badly formulated, low-level easy questions. Among them are users who either have yet not received as much math education as they would like to. Or, users who for reasons of family finances or whatever couldn't pursue math as fully and deeply as they would have wanted to. They still are eager to contribute, and we should find a way for them to do that. OTOH, if that means that we need to open the gates for questions from high schoolers... The overall quality of the site takes a hit, and we may get yet another group eager to participate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I always try to accept all points of view, even if it is not in my nature. Most of all, I understand that people have different lives and that this can give them different perspective. It is a delicate equilibrium to maintain the website at a good level, I really just wanted to know if my attempts of doing so would be considered obnoxious and possibly inappropriate.

Comment: Understood. I don't think there is anything remotely inappropriate in your approach. It is also very much in line with my own personal preference for an ideal evolution of this site. I am just trying to sound "moderate" here, but I'm not sure I'm doing a very good job :-)

Comment: I will say flat out that in my opinion there are very few understandable mathematical questions that should be closed.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: including questions that are obviously homework?

Comment: @Carl: Yes. For reasons that I’ve explained in the past.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: yet, as you know from the past, many people, including some of the hypothetical "best teachers", have argued that they do not want to participate on a site that significantly contributes towards doing other people's homework for them. This was one of the issues that was raised that the very moment this site was proposed, in fact.

Comment: @Carl: That’s their privilege. In my opinion they’re being unrealistic and not, in this context, particularly good teachers.

Comment: "Not good" is an understatement. It is *extremely despicable* when users go to great lengths to prevent others from teaching, going so far as deleting many helpful answers. The site is no longer a place for [*unfettered* teaching.](http://www.pantaneto.co.uk/issue56/odlyzko.htm) (Odlyzko, NAMS). Puerile politics is well on its way to killing mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hmm. The usual amount of soapboxing going on here. Should I join in?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: As usual, the disagreement is about the objective of the site. Answering the bad question of a very confused student is, in the mind of a teacher, undoubtedly the right thing to do. Unfortunately the permanent value in such a Q&A is non-existent, so those of us who primarily see the site as a way of building a searchable repository of quality Q&As will object. I think that may be such a question can be answered, but should soon be deleted, for lack of permanent value.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That makes no sense. Why do you think that a "bad" question can have no answer of "permanent value"?

Comment: @Bill: Brian said it himself once. The very confused students are all confused in their own unique way. Therefore clearing up the fog for one is unlikely to clear up the fog for another. We've been through this many times. Some of us just prefer to cull the weakest material. Some don't. Sigh. G'night.

Comment: @Jyrki  Sometimes, but even then a competent teacher can compose an answer that has lasting value. We've both done that many times, as have countless others.

Comment: I do not really get why there is so much debate in this thread about hypothetical great answers that could be given, when the request concerns how to react to *existing* answers (of dubious value).

Comment: @quid: Isn't it obvious? (Hint: Look at the address bar of your browser.)

Comment: Asking this question would come across as wanting to belong to the in-crowd of chat room and meta regulars, and to be told that what you do rocks.

Comment: Glad to see another conscientious mind join the community, @SilviaGhinassi. Welcome

Comment: @Silvia I have an idea: Why dont we make this site only for people who know math, and let people who struggle with math out of this site? why dont we let the people who havent had the privilege to learn math ( as you, for instance, who is pursuing a phd on a very fine institution) benefit from the experienced users here ? Not everyone has had your privilege. Remember that. I find this question to be sort of elitist.

Comment: @user135395 I am sorry I gave you this impression, which is far away from what I think; I am happy to help whoever needs help and be helped as well. Bad question $\neq$ low level question; the latter is not unwelcome to me.

Comment: What's a bad question to you might not be a bad question to me. "Do my homework for me, don't try to explain it to me because I have no interest in actually understanding this." That's an attitude that makes for a bad question. But what if in the process of answering a bad question, you come up with a really good answer? Is that really such a bad thing?

Comment: There exist many different motivators in this world and they apply differently for different people. In my experience it does not help much trying to tell people to stop being motivated by what they are motivated by. Sometimes a crappy question and/or bad attitude provokes awesome ideas and answers.

Comment: @Silvia I have no idea what you consider to be a "bad question". But, like Brian, I have seen very few questions that are not capable of sparking answers that can contribute much value to the site. Have you not?

Comment: @Bill I have seen some, hence the question. But everything being said here is very subjective, and it's good to have different points of view on the site. I disagree with the opinion that you and others share, but I respect it.

Comment: @silvia But, what is your definition of a bad question?

Comment: @Bill Is it necessary to go through this charade every single time? It has been explained at length multiple times how, for example, questions without context are not useful for the site, and I hope it's not necessary to explain again why opinion-based questions, or too broad questions, are also not useful; all of this regardless of the quality of the answers they attract.

Comment: @Najib Please read more closely. My query was addressed to the OP, not you. Asking **the OP** to explain what she means by "bad question" is most certainly not a "charade". As you surely know by now, there is a wide spectrum of opinions on these subjective matters. In particular, many users  have views that differ greatly from yours, including many highly experienced teachers.

Comment: @BillDubuque Fourth time's the charm I guess? OP has already replied to your comment (and I notice that despite your numerous attempts to reply to me, you haven't addressed her), and if you read carefully my comment isn't an answer to the question you asked. I thought I would chime in (remember that this is a public conversation) because your comment contains the implicit assumption than a question capable of "sparking answers", even good ones, is automatically useful for the site. This has been refuted numerous, hence my comment to make sure everyone is aware of that.

Comment: If you want a mathematical definition of "bad question" I obviously don't have it for you. It has been largely discussed (in previous 82 comments) what different people mean by _bad_ question; for the rest, @Najib has said everything that was needed to say.

Comment: @Silvia it would have been helpful to hear *from you* what you think makes a question bad. But, alas, nowadays it is impossible to constructively discuss anything on meta because some users will go to extreme lengths to twist the views of those that they disagree with. If you wish to know my personal views then please feel welcome to email me at my first.last name at gmail.com. You can also learn more by reading older threads. That matter is much more complex than some make it out to be.

Comment: @Bill, I am sorry, I thought it was clear. A question is bad to me if it shows a _complete_ lack of effort in understanding the problem. As I said long ago, "Giving a ready-to-use solution to someone who doesn't even understand the question won't teach them much.". So yes, the answers might be amazing pieces of math, but will be harmful to somebody. The internet is a difficult place to have constructive discussions.

Comment: @Silvia It is not at all clear from your question that you are concerned  with that narrow class of questions. The phrase "bad question" is highly overloaded and can denote all sorts of questions. It is impossible to know its denotation with inquiring. At one time it was not so difficult to have pleasant, constructive discussions on meta. Alas, those days are long gone (along with many of the best teachers/experts). The ugly site politics has left much destruction in its wake.

Comment: Some of the teachers and the experts left because there were too many "low-effort questions"; others have left because they were treated bad by other adamant users; and some just felt that life has more things to offer. Competitive wine tasting, for example.

Comment: I've never head of any such user who left because of "too many low-effort questions".

Comment: Don't the really terrible questions e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422639/which-of-the-following-statements-are-true-2-1-introduction-to-integers just get closed pretty quickly?

Comment: @RobertSoupe I do not understand your comment at all. The question you link to did not "just get closed" it got answered, too (not by an experienced user, but this seems tangential).

Comment: @BillDubuque I am not sure about 'left because of "too many low-effort questions".' but there are users that seem to have left (or MO users that never joined) because of what they consider to be a too welcoming attitude by  parts of the core community against low-effort questions. (While this is not strictly the same the latter seems actually more relevant as it would be easier to change.) This [meta MO thread](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1248/homework-and-migrating-to-math-se) contains some relevant opinions; see especially comments on my answer there.

Comment: @quid A discussion on another site about a different issue is hardly of relevance. In any case, this is not the place to reopen the huge can of worms on homework "cheating". It has already done enough damage to the site.

Comment: @BillDubuque in that discussion among others Arturo Magidin, a formerly highly active user of this site, explains what drove him away from **this** site. If you do not consider this as a relevant first-hand testimonial of what can make users leave the site I do not know what would be.

Comment: @quid This thread is not about homework cheating. Further, any such discussion should occur *here*, where inaccuracies would have been quickly pointed out. But kudos to you: there is one accurate remark there by you, viz. "I know math.SE a bit *but not very much*" (my emphasis). You should keep that in mind when you comment on very old history that you were not a part of.

Comment: @BillDubuque the type of questions discussed here and there are to a significant part the same, namely "low-effort questions", PSQ, or whatever you call them. The comments I referred to more specifically  concern precisely the communities reactions to such questions as does this questions. A user that actually left cannot comment here why they left, as they are no longer here. That is, if we care about what user that actually left have to say we will need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @quid Nonsense, said user still has an account here so they certainly can comment on this site. In any case I will not be a part of your attempt to digress by reopening the destructive "cheating" can of worms.

Comment: @BillDubuque Obviously, they could **return** to comment. I am not digressing. I pointed to comments that document that some user(s) seem not to participate in the site (anymore) due to the communities too welcoming reaction to certain "low effort questions," which felt relevant in face of you saying 'I've never head of any such user who left because of "too many low-effort questions".'

Comment: @quid That's quite the tangent you're on there. Please do not ping me any further since, as I said, I have no interest in further diverting this thread.

Comment: The frequently repeated "What have you tried?" is over-used.  Say someone posts a question that says: (a) Find the derivative of this function. (b) What does the fact that the derivative is positive on this particular interval tell you about blah blah blah? (c) Show that the second derivative can never exceed whatever. (d) What can you conclude about the asymptotic behavior of and so on and so forth? I would not as "What have you tried?".  Instead I would cast doubt on whether the poster is actually asking any question, as opposed to copying a question without understanding it.

Comment: Here's an example of a question that appears to be a cut and paste from a high school math book. I am tempted to answer it with a long essay on Euclidean and other demonstrations of the Pythagorean Theorem, with a side trip into the history of attempts to square the circle. All with semicolons separating the clauses, since it's supposed to be answered in a complete sentence. As it is, I'm afraid my comment there might be a little snarky. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432285/266049

Comment: @MichaelHardy A) I'd close that due to too many questions asked in the same post.  B) And what would you do with your doubt on whether or not the OP copied the question from somewhere else or not?  Nothing?  Close it?  I think asking what they've tried is at least something objectively doable.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : What I would do with my "doubt" is express it in a comment below the question.

Comment: This recent post seems a bit related: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508),

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I advise against commenting. As the cacophony of comments in this thread shows, engaging in a dispute with those users doesn't lead anywhere good.

Downvote and move on.

Comment: You speak the truth.

Comment: Downvote the question or the answer(s)? I do not think a good answer (a good answer to a bad question, too, assuming that we may define what a "bad question" really is) should be downvoted for "political" reasons. We are doing math, after all, not sociology.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Encouraging bad questions (by answering them) is not a useful thing to do; hence, "not useful" reason for downvoting.

Comment: @NormalHuman: I do not agree. An answer is just an answer, every hidden "encouragement" is just a personal interpretation; I believe the real poison is to raise someone's standard to everyone's standard without an explicit agreement.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well spoken, Jack.

Comment: Downvote plus comment is good too.

Comment: When people stop complaining, that means they've given up or stopped caring.

Comment: @Jack: A user who wants bad questions out of the site (for some definition of *bad*) does not have many options. Downvoting those questions will not discourage the askers, because they A) got what they wanted, when somebody answered, B) use a throwaway account anyway. Downvoting the answers OTOH is more effective. It may discourage the answerers, because at least some of them worry about imaginary reputation points. If enough of those answerers consequently stop answering those questions that, in turn, will make the askers turn away from this site (which is the goal here).

Comment: (cont'd) and voting is more or less by definition a political phenomenon. The correctness of a mathematical argument is not decided by popular vote. Its elegance could be judged well by peers. But  users clearly cannot appreciate arguments beyond their current level of sophistication, and consequently we cannot rely on votes to determine the mathematical value of a contribution.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: your point is pretty convincing, but I would add another question to the discussion - do we *really need* to keep such line against bad/HW questions, by installing a huge "*stay away*!" signal? Wouldn't be better to (at least) try to turn such questions into better ones, and to turn throwaway accounts into regular users?

Comment: @Jack: More good questions is good, but who will do it?

Comment: @Hurkyl: I believe anyone with the edit privilege may turn a bad question into a decent one in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, lots of people are *allowed* to do it, but who will *actually* do it? In practice,the choice is between leaving it open and closing it, because people usually won't spend that extra effort; it will take some campaigning to get people to start doing that. IIRC, the idea has only been proposed previously by the people who don't care much about keeping these questions, but the vocal defenders of these questions were wholly uninterested in the compromise, so the idea never got off the ground.

Answer (score 12):

As long as your comment is polite, I see no reason why you should not make any appropriate suggestion. However, if you feel that a question is indeed bad, and you have the requisite reputation, then it might be more appropriate to cast a close vote.

Note that the reasons that people might have answered that question will vary depending on what you define as a "bad question".  What is defined as a bad question has undergone quite a bit of debate in the last year or so. One of the more recent reasons to close a question deals with the lack of context.

Although I am a moderator, what follows is simply my opinion and not necessarily that of the moderation staff.

There are bad questions and there are good questions that lack context.  I fully agree that bad questions should simply be closed.  However, good questions that lack context are not necessarily bad questions.

The people who have been on the site a long time, started when there was not a requirement for context.  If a question was interesting, you answered it. If it seemed like a homework question, you gave a hopefully inspiring hint.

A year back, I believe due to the uncertainty as to whether questions were homework or not, the homework tag was removed. In order to close the questions that seemed like homework, questions started being closed for lack of context.

Don't get me wrong; context can be interesting as well as useful for forming an appropriate answer, or for knowing when a hint is more useful than a full answer.  However, the context of a question may not be of any interest for people who look up that question in the future.

However, if a question is interesting in itself, and it seems pretty clear that the question is not a homework question, people tend to answer with or without context. After all, we are here to learn math, not necessarily learn people's backgrounds or what they have been reading.

Comment: You are the first user to use the word "context" in this discussion...

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Rather it seems to suggest that OP mistakes "good questions" for "bad questions."

Comment: There is no "requirement for context". Rather, there are some (mostly inexperienced) users who (unfortunately) personally believe in such requirements, no matter how detrimental they may be to sharing mathematical knowledge.

Comment: As the only context for what a bad question is is given in the [cited question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions), and that question talks about the missing context criteria, I felt it appropriate to mention context and its relation to bad questions.

Comment: Still this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @quid: I said that bad questions should be closed. However, how one communicates that to people who have answered is a tougher question. My opinion about what is or is not a bad question may help explain the responses they might get to such a comment as they are suggesting.

Comment: The question is: "Can I try to tell experienced users not to answer bad questions?" and then differently "Would a comment like that be considered rude or somehow bad by the community?" You do not address this in any way. Rather it seems you explain that  you disagree with the premise that questions should be not answered. // On your edits: not really and even if so, why not  make it explicit.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for your point of view, anyway. I just wanted to point out that I am referring to _bad_ questions, not good ones which lack contexts. Also, the situation I am talking about is more like the following: while some users try to comment and give helpful hints, some other users arrives and post a full answer. But, again, different people have different opinions on the matter.

Comment: @Silvia Even "bad" questions can provide the spark that motivates excellent teachers. Don't lose sight of the fact that the purpose of the sight is not to teach how to ask questions but, rather, to teach *mathematics*.

Comment: @BillDubuque "A good teacher can transform almost any question into a good teaching opportunity." Maybe so, but plenty of answer on the site don't, which seems like a main concern judging from "Also, I think a real dedicate teacher doesn't belong to this category. Giving a ready-to-use solution to someone who doesn't even understand the question won't teach them much."

Comment: @quid Those are exactly my questions, and those you are saying would be my comments. //included your note on the spelling of my name.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Unfortunately your previous comment raises another divisive issue. We do not all agree on whether the purpose of the site is to *teach mathematics* or to *become a repository of mathematical knowledge*. Thankfully the two goals are not mutually exclusive. We probably disagree on which of these goals is more important when forming policies, but I'm fairly sure that I'm about to veer off-topic.

Comment: @quid: I have prefaced my post with something that is hopefully more addressed to the question and ties what I have said after into that.

Comment: I really like that last paragraph. That is a difference between me and the "no-context" hardliners.

Comment: @Rob I think you mean "poor question" not "poor answer". I am tempted to retract my upvote after that edit, since I think it is extremely unwise to recommend that such comments be placed on the main site. These will only lead to arguments on main, and that is very destructive.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I am not recommending that sort of comment; however, I don't see any reason to repress someone's opinion, if politely expressed. Comments are ephemeral and if they are rude or not constructive, they can be removed.

Comment: @Rob I read your first paragraph as an endorsement. Perhaps you should rewrite it if that is not what you meant (but my upvote still stands on other points). The main site should not be used to argue policy matters, The fact that rude comments can be removed does not imply that they will not cause damage. Indeed, we have lost some extremely talented teachers due to rudeness. Let's not encourage policies that could cause further such losses.

Comment: (Re some previous comments) The primary purpose of this site is to answer questions. To some extent, necessarily, that will involve teaching and disseminating mathematics. But the primary purpose of this site is not teaching (e.g. Kahn academy, or a good blog series) or dissemination (e.g. the arXiv, or a good blog series).

Comment: Exactly - the real tension is with homework, rather than context. At least two options are possible: (1) tell people that homework problems are not allowed, and close questions that seem to be homework. This would allow good questions to be asked without context. (2) We could say that homework questions are OK, but that all questions need to be well written *regardless* whether they are homework. Personally, I would like (1), but several people argued forcefully in other meta posts that (according to them) option (1) is no good. Unfortunately, that has led us to (2).

Comment: Thanks for the expansion. I revoked my dv.

Comment: Agree with @Carl. IMHO the "no-context" is mostly a euphemism for "somebody-do-my-homework". And this close reason is IMVHO occasionally misapplied. It would be simpler to just disallow all homework questions, but that is also IMHO suboptimal. If only because my preference is for us to attract more math enthusiasts among upperclassmen and grad students. The math enthusiasts at all levels are welcome. Those who simply need to pass calculus and/or finite math to get their degree are better served by people who are paid to serve them.

Comment: @CarlMummert The solution is much simpler - ignore questions that are not to your taste. Do not try to force your tastes onto other users.

Comment: I love it when someone claims that a certain behavior is no less than a poison to this community and the site (true or not),  and then someone suggest they simply ignore it. If you had poison in your tea, you can ignore it all you want, and still get poisoned. If someone thinks that something is poisoning the site, *how* can they ignore it?

Comment: @Asaf One man's meat is another man's poison.

Comment: @Jyrki: That’s a false dichotomy: there’s a whole continuum ranging from enthusiasts to those who couldn’t care less save that they want to pass a particular course. And those at the latter end of the spectrum are best served by those who can and want to help them; being paid is irrelevant.

Comment: @Asaf: I mostly manage to do so, at least since my return. Mostly. And I see a fundamental difference between those whose preferences entail exclusion and those whose preferences entail inclusion: the former curtail the latter’s possibilities, while the latter merely wish the former to ignore questions that they don’t like or that don’t interest them.

Comment: @Bill: That is very true. It's still poison.

Comment: @Brian: So your solution to the rising overpopulation and the famine, war and pestilence it entails is simply to ignore most of the people? I don't think it's gonna work.

Comment: Poor analogies such as "One man's meat is another man's poison" @Bill?

Comment: @Najib Get a clue: that comment was made precisely to illustrate the uselessness of the "logic".frequently employed by Asaf.

Comment: @Bill It was a pretty poor way to illustrate that then. It certainly looked like you took the same logic and used it to make a point that what some people consider to be poison is edible by other people. (I saw you edited your comment to add "Get a clue": why are you so aggressive?)

Comment: Let me avoid all analogies.  The position that the presence of some content should just be ignore by those that take issue at it, as if it were nothing, seems overly simplistic to me. If this were so easy, why do we limit the scope of the site at all? Why not let users  just ask or post whatever they want: recipes, reviews of movies, stories what they did during their summer-vacation, etc. Maybe some would enjoy it. Why do we curtail users' ability to express themselves on this site  freely? Everybody that might have some issue with some content: just ignore it.

Comment: @quid That's very far from "avoiding all analogies".

Comment: @BillDubuque please be specific.

Comment: @Asaf: Neither do I. But MSE isn’t the world, and the analogy is strained to the point of absurdity.

Comment: @Bill: I suppose that you could argue that quid's comment uses analogy in implying that being allowed to post recipes on a math site is analogous to posting mathematical questions that some users consider bad in one way or another. I’d say simply that it’s rhetorical hot air, all show and no substance.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Let is not get hung up on this tangent. Let me just redact the claim about analogies. On the rest, your choice of words speaks for itself. The site has *some* scope, and I think most agree there is some point in having *some* scope and enforcing this. Where exactly one draws the line is a question one might reasonable disagree about, but your "merely ignore it" is  overly simplistic.

Comment: @Brian: What quid said in the last comment hits the nail on the head (with another nail, if you follow the conventions set by Futurama). My point, in that strained analogy, was that MSE is now a large site. We need to treat it as such. Ignoring problems that seem to be harder and harder to ignore is not a solution. Or in other words, ignoring your problems never solves them. At best you can hope for them to solve themselves, but this is not this kind of problem, I fear.

Comment: Furthermore, it is for me harder to (try to) ignore the low-quality math Q and A than it'd be to ignore a thread about what users did during the vacations or what their favorite beverage is. On the one hand, it would be more visible from the title. On the other hand, I would feel less of an obligation to intervene when there is too much deviation from what I consider a reasonable answer. Finally, such "get-to-know-you" threads detached from the actual subject do exists on some discussion-boards; it is not that far fetched. Or why not a Q: "What is your favorite snack while doing math?"

Comment: @quid: I disagree. I find it no harder to ignore *I need an answer ASAP* than to ignore a question on differential geometry, a subject about which I know nothing. The basic line is very simple: the question should be mathematical and understandable. The most important refinement is *Is it a duplicate?*, not so much to save effort as to make more of the available answers readily accessible. There are perhaps a few other useful refinements, but for the most part anything else is imposition of an arbitrary prejudice that restricts the choices of other answerers.

Comment: @Asaf: And that’s the fundamental difference: I don’t see that the size of MSE presents any problem in this respect.

Comment: @Brian: The only way to ignore something which seems to be more and more commonplace is to reduce participation in the site. And I'm more than sure that you're not suggesting that anyone leaves the site. But in effect, this is what's going to happen when wading through the muck becomes too difficult.

Comment: @Brian It seems to me that rules in general are about restricting choices. Is that a bad thing? The basic line of living in a society isn't very complicated, and yet we have law books thousands (if not millions) of pages long. It's not unthinkable that in a community of thousands of active users, something more than a few naive rules are needed. And what about the choices of the SE designers who decided to forbid questions that are too broad, opinion-based or off-topic (the closure reasons that you conveniently omitted)? What about the choices of the community who decided what's off-topic?

Comment: Ignoring bad content is as easy as ignoring what Bill calls *the deletion squad*. No, ignoring the deletion squad is easier because those people do not restrict your freedom to post in any way whatsoever. I turned away from sci.math because it was, as an unmoderated site, overrun by Cantor-disprovers and other crackpots. This is moderated. And we damn well are not going to allow this to be overrun by users dumping their loads here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have no problem with "The basic line is very simple: the question should be mathematical and understandable." in itself, I would even consider it as a reasonable stance, *with the understanding that* this is your/an *opinion* what is/should be the scope of the site.  I cannot follow "for the most part anything else is imposition of an arbitrary prejudice" though.

Comment: As already mentioned in  my mind that the site is about mathematics and thus the question should be mathematical is also restriction that is imposed and I do not see any fundamental difference between this restriction, which also was imposed at some point in some way, and certain other restrictions one might impose.  Perhaps there is somebody that thinks Math&CS  should go together as the dividing line is too arbitrary an imposition or all Sciences sites etc. (Indeed very early on TCS was somehow part of MO, then they split off. Much later a remerge of MO and TCS was proposed.)

Comment: Conversely, some others might think it'd be better to have a math-site restricted to undergraduate and above. I cannot find anything objectionable in this, or  any of the opinions I listed. In my mind how to develop  the site(s) is a question of practicality, efficience, and preference. Yet not something set in stone.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:"Jyrki: That’s a false dichotomy: there’s a whole continuum ranging from enthusiasts to those who couldn’t care less save that they want to pass a particular course." Now that I cooled down a bit I admit that my attempt to paint a black&white picture was misguided. Few things about people are.B&W. I cannot give a precise definition of what I find acceptable and what I would rather not see here. It is fuzzy.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the reason to ask "Why are you doing this when the question should be closed" presumes that *your* assessment of what should be allowed is better than that of others. Those who, with great experience, answer these question have probably actually thought about it before doing so. *I* certainly have. So to answer your actual question: go ahead and write the comment if you like. I probably will ignore it.

A little more detail. From your comments, you seem to feel that answering HW questions promotes bad behavior, but I don't believe it. Others think it makes it hard to teach math classes and evaluate students accurately, and I don't believe that, either. My basis for that view is based on data:

If answering homework questions encourages more of them, *why aren't there tons of people who've done nothing but ask HW questions*, since many apparent HW questions, without context, *do* get answered?

I suspect that most September HW questions come from people who rapidly realize that if they can't handle the first HW assignment, they should drop the course (or get a tutor, or ...) and quickly disappear. That's a win-win situation: they get some help, but it turns out to not be the help they thought they wanted. They wanted to know how to compute a sum, but in reading the answer, discover that they *really* need help in choosing a course of study, because doing stuff like this is way over their head.

We have an amazingly high signal-to-noise ratio here. I recently answered [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431042/how-do-you-calculate-a-sum-over-a-polynomial/1431090#1431090) that was badly phrased and lacked context, and which sounded, at first blush, like a HW question. @robjohn read the question so quickly that he saw the question he expected rather than the one that was (badly) asked [and I loved his answer to that question!]. Others did similar things. But we could have all downvoted it because it sounded like an attempt to get an answer to HW problem, written by someone not very good at writing math, and that would have been a pity. As it turned out, it got refined into a pretty decent question with a somewhat interesting answer.

Short summary: I think we're doing fine, and our response to HW questions probably doesn't matter one tiny bit in the big picture.  It certainly doesn't matter to me, even though I teach math classes now and then.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the big picture, we could just worry about little ol' math.se.

Comment: "why aren't there tons of people who've done nothing but ask HW questions": talk about a loaded question! There *are* tons of people who do nothing but ask HW questions!

Comment: No, there really aren't. There are in early Sept. each year, but mostly it's pretty decent. Show me five users who asked questions yesterday, and who have more than ten HW questions in the last year, and I'll start to change my mind. That *should* be easy if there are so many of them.  Instead, I claim most fade out really fast, and learn, from their questions and the answers, that they're really not cut out for this.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I have to say I agree with you on almost all the line, and I am quite surprised your reply got downvoted so hard, in favour of a more punitive attitude towards newcomers.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I'm used to others not agreeing with me. And if someone wants to show evidence that my claim --- that serial-hw-questioners are rare --- is wrong, I'll even be willing to alter my views.  But I'm glad to find that we mostly agree.

Comment: One more question for the doubters: in what way does not answering HW questions actually dissuades the questions? Do you imagine that the kid taking Algebra II really sits down and reads through a few hundred old questions and says "Wow, the ones that sound like HW don't seem to have answers!" Of course not. That kid just asks the question and hopes. Maybe it keeps that kid from asking a *second* question, but again...are there really a lot of serial HW-question-askers? To paraphrase Cuba Gooding, Jr.: Show me the data!

Comment: @JohnHughes Most of these users are using throwaway accounts, so finding one that's been active for a year and has asked 10 questions is going to be hard... RE: last comment, have you spoken with people in real-life about math.SE? "Oh, that site where you can get your HW done for you?" is the most common response. If a user arrives on the site, sees the front page only has reasonable questions (because the bad ones have been closed and deleted), and the people around him/her haven't told him/her "hey you know what, go on this site to get your HW done for free", the situation will get better.

Comment: I *have* spoken to people about it. Mostly they know about stackoverflow in some form, and the only one that had actual knowledge of MSE said, "Oh, one of my Ph.D. students got help with just the step he was stuck on for one of the theorems in his dissertation, and actually thanked and cited MSE." It's true that right now, 8 of the 15 questions on the first page are HW, but it's also the start of September. As for "throwaway accounts," creating an MSE account per question seems like ... kind of a high barrier to entry. I suppose you and I will continue to believe what we want to believe. :)

Comment: @John You don't need to _create_ an account to ask a question here. You can just type your question, and provide an email address (I think the address you provide need not even be real or valid, but if you don't provide a valid email address you "own", losing your cookie will lose you the access to the unregistered "account" you asked from). It's not a particularly high barrier. We have a few instances of users who have created a lot of unregistered accounts, each for one or a few questions, used so long until the cookie was cleared, then the next account was created. Not even ill-intentioned.

Comment: They just didn't care, since creating a new unregistered account is so easy.