# Should I edit the question before starting a bounty, or start a new question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, editing, etiquette, bounty

I have a question I would like to start a bounty on. But I would like to edit the question to add the possibility for a stronger result. The question I want to start a bounty on is this question:

[For an integrable function, does there exist a sequence of partitions with this property.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123438/for-an-integrable-function-does-there-exist-a-sequence-of-partitions-with-this)

But I would like to modify it like this:

For a partition $\Pi$ we define $f_{\Pi}(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)\cdot1_{\{x: |f(x)|<\infty\}}(t_i)1_{x \in [t_i,t_i+1)}(t)$. I also want to know if there exists a sequence of partitions $\Pi_n$ such that $\int_{[a,b]}|f(t)-f_{\Pi_n}(t)|dt\rightarrow0$ or $\int_{[a,b]}|f(t)-f_{\Pi_n}(t)|^2dt\rightarrow0$.

**Is it most appropriate to edit the question and include the new info, or ask a new quesiton which include all the info, but it will also include the former question? I am unsure if it is allowed to edit the question because it changes the question by a lot.**

Comment: There've been no answers to the question yet, so I see no harm in changing it. (You might want to delete it while you edit in the change, to prevent an answer to the original version from slipping in, then undelete it once it's in the form you want.)

Comment: @BarryCipra: I agree that without any Answers, it is harmless to edit the Question.  However I think a self-deleted Question is not allowed to be edited in the current SE rules.  I think this was a source of some kind of abuse related to the changes going without scrutiny, but my recollection is vague.

Comment: user394334:  Were you able to work out a solution yourself to the original problem?  If so, adding a sketch of that solution would be nice context.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I edited it and started a bounty.@hardmath No, I wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: As a follow-up to hardmath's second comment above, I would suggest adding your current progress on the questions, even if tentative or primitive, as contexts to abide by [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).