# Full solution in comments after question was closed.

Tags: discussion, comment, closed-questions, low-quality-posts

Recently, there has been some users who post a significant amount of things in the comments to questions of low-quality questions. To me what they put in the comments is really a full solution of the question.

This is frustrating for those that were asking the OP for more context of the question or were giving nudges to a solution by themselves without giving out the complete solution. It's also an issue because this seems like it's a loophole in closing questions.

I saw a case today where a full solution was posted in the comments after the question was already closed as off-topic.  There was another case where a detailed solution spanning two comments to a low-quality question was closed as off-topic afterwards.

Should there be some ways to enforce the comments of off-topic questions? I am not entirely sure what the purpose of these users are; it's clearly not for reputations as they're not posting answers. Otherwise there's no point in closing questions because people will just type their solution in the comments after it being closed.

Comment: You can certainly flag any user's comment if you have noticed a pattern, who is answering in comments, for moderator attention citing the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1).  The same enforcement applies to answers and comments that answer.

Comment: Your second paragraph tells that you are trying to use the website as a virtual classroom. However, look at it. It is not designed for that. It is designed to establish relations Question-Answers, Topics-Questions. It is also designed to be a collaboration and it is the intention of the owners to make as many people as possible be able to participate. The EQS was redacted by part of the users of the website and some of its aspects were injected by users who never understood that this website simply cannot work as a virtual classroom. Well you get frustrated when you try to go against reality.

Comment: I have been part of this collaboration since before it was founded. What is that, 20 years? I have seen loads of versions of "what have you tried" comments posted on questions. They almost never prevent an answerable question, that someone can figure out, from getting connected to an answer one way or another.

Comment: Sometimes it is unclear that I have answered the question at the time I wrote the comment because I was in fact only trying to clarify the question. (“Did you mean this trivial thing? Because Counterexample”. “Oh, yes I did! Thank you!” ) would you suggest I stop doing this to clarify questions? I could have put a longer comment to signal what minor variations would have made a good (or even open) question but I think that would be too enthusiastic on my end

Comment: yes @CalvinKhor did answer one of my question like that... [Socratic dialogue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNDYUlxNIAA) as a tool of teaching is very underrated

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Asking for clarification, or asking a user to pin down an ambiguous expression, etc., is perfectly fine.  We encourage users to assist in this way, and it would also be helpful to suggest to the asker to edit their post to include their answers to your question.  And if they have an "aha" moment after a comment exchange with you, encourage them to post an answer to their question.Those kind of comments are encouraged!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation amWhy and @Adil :) That is a good suggestion. Sometimes though, I guess the OP would also agree that the question wasn't "great", so I leave it for roomba as in Xander's answer.

Comment: Aren't comments where you would make suggestions/clarifications to improve a question?  Seems wrong to cut off the only avenue for re-opening.

Comment: @Randall I guess you're right. It's just that the abuse of comments for closed questions seem to be more rife than legitimate comments. Do you have an idea for an alternative mechanism that might work?

Comment: "am not entirely sure what the purpose of these users are; it's clearly not for reputations as they're not posting answers." It seems likely that they are just trying to help whoever asked the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think that fewer people will write an answer in the comments because of the lack of reputation gain, so closing a question still does have a purpose. Also, closed questions often get deleted by the [roomba](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) faster, so there's that too.

From my understanding, the current way to deal with this would be

1. Leave a polite comment pointing them to the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) and asking them not to give hints/answers to low-quality questions.
2. If a user consistently keeps commenting the answers, then flag one of their comments for moderator attention.

Comment: It happens frequently enough, so best not to be dismissive about it.  I've noticed an uptick in such comments as well.  Indeed, we seem to always have user accounts that set out to do just that: answer in comments. And upon politely addressing them, thumb their noses at it.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry! I didn't intend to come off as dismissive about it. I definitely see a bunch of answers in comments (to both low and high quality questions), so I agree it's a real problem. I just meant that closing low-quality questions is still a worthy goal.

Comment: No worries, I did not mean that you were.  The ones most dismissive are the commenters who answer in comments.  I.e., they do so intentionally most often.  You wrote a fine answer!

Comment: This is what puzzles me. Why would someone leave a solution in the comments to low quality posts, if that has no influence in their reputation? Yet, it still happens and it's a bit puzzling what their motivation is.

Comment: @daruma People like showing off. They see the question, they solve it because it is an interesting question, and then they think, "since I've already solved it, why not share the answer?"

Comment: @MikeEarnest What you describe is not *showing off*, it's just helping, albeit not necessarily the best way. AAMOF, I quite often post **hints** in comments, whether the question is closed or not. Motivation? Well, I do not always agree with the question being closed in the first place (yes, it happens). But above all I consider receiving a hint is still an incentive to actually do some work on the question, which is the best I can hope, from a student. I always found that a hint is better than a full answer. But I know opinions differ about this, here.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You are right, many people are doing it to be helpful. But sometimes people are doing it show off. (Proof: admittedly, this has sometimes been my mindset when leaving such comments).

Comment: @daruma Did it occur to you, and others mentionning this, that we are not necessarily here to get more reputation points? The *only* interest I have in those points is the site features they enable. The rest is an unnecessary burden.

Comment: The entire premise of the EoQS is that ***it is not helpful for students overall*** to receive answers, nor answers in comments, as it enables them to find others to do their thinking, their learning, for them, so when they do not have you all in their pocket, they'll crash and burn.

Comment: Also, @Daruma, many, are answering in comments in protest, to make a point that "no one is ever gonna stop them from giving freebie answers... You are right to be concerned.  Answering in comments in flaggable so they become deletable.  What Jean and Mike speak of, Jean-Claude in particular, many are doing it to *show off*, period.

Comment: @amWhy There is something fundamentally dishonest with the current rule. 1/ the site is supposed to be a *reference*, that is give good answers to as many questions as possible. Fine. 2/ We shall only answer a question if enough work is shown. So the guy will get a full answer, but he has worked on it after all, maybe he *deserves* it. Fine. 3/ Oh, but wait, what if another student passing by gets an answer for free? Once an answer is here, it's for anyone, forever. Even for those who don't even bother to try. I agree it's not good to give a full answer for free. But that's what we are doing.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut (1) I don't think we can do anything about future visitors, unfortunately (2) effort isn't the only context, source and motivations also count i.e. the OP could have done no work just like future visitors (3) Searching must get due credit, sometimes even over posting a decent duplicate question. If you search and find my answer despite having done no work, then for me that's better than formatting a question out of it and having people here search for dupes. Searching is a skill, as regular dupes vouch for. What I am ok with, though, and I spoke about this sometime ago...

Comment: ... on a meta post, is that one can invite a reader to improve their low-quality question by providing a mixture of starting points for solving the question via good hints (and posting attempts) and also provide hints that improve the question (e.g. provide source, motivation etc.) if someone is skilled in this, they can simultaneously get OP to improve the question and keep interest and faith that their question will be addressed, given that someone knows something about it. This kind of "mix and match" can be nice to see in posts. I like to do it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I understand your point, and I almost agree. But really the problem is your (1). Actually, even giving a full answer to someone who has tried and failed should be a problem: when a teacher is giving homework, it's also to evaluate his students - not their searching skills. The site cannot exist if we consider only what's best for students. So I prefer to give hints, and when a question is interesting for me (to improve or maintain *my* skills), I give an answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Truth be told, I discovered Math.SE by searching on Google an answer to a tough question asked by a colleague at work. And I stayed because it helps me learn new things and not forget too much, while at the same time it may help others. As to the rules...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for opening my eyes to something I never considered in your first comment. You can see that I was never a teacher! Having said that, I wonder if this is something considered significant when we look at the design of such a site : I don't think anybody put on that teacher's hat. We don't entertain PSQs : a teacher may be inclined to do so since that presents a pedagogical opportunity (let's forget about whether it's "deserved" or not). Next, your point on full answers vs hints : I see the opinion hinging towards full answers : to create "authoritativeness"...

Comment: ... in an answer, at least to the degree of effectiveness the answerer thinks about. You provide valid counterexamples towards hints. So yes, I wonder how much a teacher's point of view was considered in the design of this site. In the light of EoQS, I think providing a loose hint/answer (which means that a very tight hint like a mere starting point is very good in the comments) in the comments should spell trouble though : it is appeasement of a low-quality question, all said and done. I never thought about your first point, though, so that's a very good point out. +1 to the comment.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It's a question of point of view: the site shouldn't even try to consider students questions as special. And in some way, it does not. But, if the goal is to have a good reference site, it doesn't matter at all that the OP has tried anything. What counts in the long run is how interesting/reusable/general the question is, and how well it is stated. The OP's efforts are then totally irrelevant. By *trying* to do something special about students, we are changing the site's intent, and IMO, failing. But this is only my opinion, and I don't expect it's shared by many here.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I suppose that was the role that context was supposed to play. I recall a Lord_Farin answer : they say that source and motivation should be the OP's contribution to context, and the attempt should come third, as a saving grace more than anything. So yes, you are correct :  but it will take a sea of change to sort out the whole attempt circus, because the first thing you see on a low-quality post is either a template message or a version of "what have you tried?" Hopefully a shift to this prioritization of context can be beneficial to teachers.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Poor one-line PSQs, tend to lead to short AWE (answers without explanations, void of text.  Those do not a good resource make.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ( 1) While I think that there are folk on the site who see the quality standards as a kind of gatekeeping to prevent cheating, that is certainly not *my* view of things.  The quality standards are about maintaining the quality of this site as a searchable database.  It is nigh certain that students are using Math SE to cheat, but that isn't something that we can (or, frankly, *should*) try to adjudicate.  Rather, the quality standards exist to ensure that questions are fully formed, that they are searchable, and that they are likely to be of use to future askers.

Comment: (2) The umpteenth copy of "How do I evaluate this integral?" or "What is the solution to this system of equations?" is, generally speaking, extremely unlikely to be of any use to anyone except the original asker and, perhaps, any other student working out of the same text.  As such, these kinds of questions (problem statement questions) are not a good fit for Math SE.  The fact that there is a high degree of overlap between PSQs and questions of dubious ethical merit is relevant here, but is not the primary motivation for trying to discourage such questions.

Comment: (3) I agree that the asker's attempts are irrelevant in the vast majority of cases.  I really wish that we could get past the idea that "context" = "attempt".  Personally, I don't think that "attempts" provide very good context---generally, they just contribute noise.  There are *much* better ways of providing context:  give a source, provide some motivation, explain which tools might be relevant, state related definitions, etc.  I would be more than happy to remove "show an attempt" as a form of context, but there is a vocal contingent here which seems to want to retain it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I agree with the sentiment from other comments that EoQS is a heavy handed approach that does not really solve any problem. I would just add that it is also inherently and hopelessly incongruent. Marking a question as a duplicate, for example, is practiced and encouraged by the very same EoQS promoters. Though, of course, it provides instant gratification to the OP, regardless of the quality of the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think (3) is the key point for me at least. I have seen dozens of cases where in otherwise poor-quality questions are met with a comment or two asking "well what have you tried?" but have never seen someone suggest updating the question with the assignment from which the question comes nor the level of instruction. I would also reiterate that "context" is a very nebulous term, especially for someone unfamiliar with the years of discussions on Math SE about question quality, as almost all askers of PSQs are.

Comment: @JackGallagher the problem is that some pretend that it is impossible for many users to provide context other than maybe what they have tried. The "attempt" then became a least common denominator.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut to put it bluntly, the problem is not that the rule is dishonest, it is that your understanding of it seems to be incomplete. A main problem with PSQs and alike is that there scope is  are poorly defined.  The attempt can provide a clue what the actual issue is.

Comment: @quid I certainly prefer Xander Henderson's interpretation. However, it's not how it's done in practice. My understanding may be incomplete, but then this misunderstanding seems to be widely shared. What I have seen a lot (and done, I confess) is: probable homework -> no attempt -> vote to close, with a very explicit reference to the fact that someone who asks us to do his homework will not get it here. If it's bad (and now I think it is, thinking about it and reading Xander's answers), then it should be explicitly stated what the intent of the rule *really* is.

Comment: @quit But I think this behavior from answerers comes mainly from the fact that poorly written questions have flooded the site for years, which is a consequence of the success of the site. It wasn't much of a problem when I came on Math.SE for the first time, in 2013. Hence the comments I have seen that the rules where not as stringent back then. But I still think helping askers to write good questions is the ultimate goal, and the "attempt" rule is not the best way (as Xander points out, it adds noise, not quality).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm not sure that everyone, including the moderators, needs to agree on "what the intent of the rule really is", in the sense that the "no homework" and "good quality questions" camps have a lot in common. These camps can bicker, sure, but I don't think focusing on the "intent" of the rule is helpful, and I do not expect the moderators to have a single motivation for it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut there is no "attempt" rule, there is a "context" rule. Did you recently read the homework faq and How to ask a good question?

Answer (score 2):

The SE network generally discourages folk from posting answers in comments.  If you want to answer a question, post an *answer*.  This ensures that answers are easier to find via search.  Thus, per Meta SE policy, don't post answers in comments.  Answers in comments should be flagged and deleted.

[removes moderator hat]

That being said, my opinion follows:

If a question is poorly received and has no answers, it can be [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).  So *if* one must answer a low-quality question, *then* it is my opinion that it is preferable to post that answer in the comments, rather than to post an answer.  In many such cases, everyone walks away happy:  the asker has an answer to their question, the answerer gets the dopamine hit of helping out another person, and the question is eventually deleted and doesn't clutter up the database.

In summary:

- Don't post answers to low quality questions.
- Seriously.  Don't post answers to low quality questions.
- If you *must* post an answer, do so in the comments.

[puts moderator hat back on]

Comment: I don't particularly agree with your second point.  No one "must do anything", unless someone is holding a gun to ones head.  In that case, to save ones life, sure, post an answer in the comments.  Unfortunately, there are a handful of users trying to sabotage the EoQS by posting answers in comments, *even after the question has been closed*.  So I've got mixed feelings on the second point (mod hat off), but for the most part, thanks for posting!!

Comment: This seems to completely contradict the point of EOQS. The entire point of closure is that these questions *should **not** be answered here, **at all***, even if they're almost guaranteed to to be deleted. Letting answers-in-comments slide defeats that purpose and sabotages the EOQS.

Comment: Interesting point about quality standards vs site quality. It feels a bit like *letter and spirit of the law*. In the long run, what matters most is the site quality: good questions, good answers. In my opinion, we tend to close too quickly, and to delete too slowly. But maybe it's just an impression.

Comment: Really surprised about the first paragraph. On not-low-quality questions, this site has a very strong tradition of answers in comments. So much that I have seen  moderators do it from time to time, and in any case no enforcement whatsoever has ever existed (on sister sites it is common to see "no answers in comments" comments, while no such thing happens in MSE).

Comment: @Nij The point was that such questions should not be answered.  However, if a user is compelled to answer a question (which they shouldn't, but some people can't seem to help themselves), I think it is better to answer in the comments, as this won't prevent a question from being automatically deleted.  Again, the first point is "Don't answer low quality questions."  The second point is "If you decide to ignore the first point, please do so in a way that makes cleanup easier."

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Honestly, I feel somewhat differently.  I think that we should be faster to close, but slower to delete (indeed, if we are faster to close, then automatic deletion, which can take longer, can be more effective).  If we are fast to close, we give the asker time to improve their question before several (possibly irrelevant) answers are posted.

Comment: @Xander  Of course, in the case of sufferers with Answering OCD, I agree it is better, when the compulsion exceeds their control, to answer only in comments.  But I'd add that if that happens too frequently, they need to seek treatment for their OCD.  Just like if someone has a compulsion to steak naked in public, there will be consequences, and I'd hope the intervention would first be mandated treatment for their OCD.

Comment: I think it would be better just to remove the whole "if you have to answer then..." bit. True though it may be, it's probably better left unsaid.

Comment: If someone who asks a PSQ has their question solved in the comments, then doesn't that encourage them to post more PSQs?

Comment: @joe Yes.  But it is easier to clean up a bad question with an answer in the comments than a bad question with an answer posted as an answer.  Y'all seem to want something black-and-white, and I am trying to present something with a little bit of nuance.  There are *relative* badnesses here:  it is *worse* to answer a bad question with an answer than with a comment.  Neither behaviour is really appropriate, but one is clearly worse than the other.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: It would be better to shoplift than to conduct an armed robbery, but it would be strange to say "if you *must* steal from someone, then shoplift". You're right that it would be better for someone to answer in the comments than to post a full answer, but I fear that this dilutes the message that PSQs should not be answered at all. I don't necessarily disagree with you—I just share user1729's view that these things are better left unsaid.

Comment: @Joe I disagree with you regarding things being left unsaid.  As we seem to have reached an impasse, I will bow out of the conversation, now.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Okay. I'd just like you to know that I respect your opinion and I am generally supportive of the actions that you have taken as a moderator to improve this site. Please don't let polite disagreement from me obscure this fact.

Comment: I am sorry, @Martin.  I was too familiar with the comment thread and original post to understand who wrote what, when.  And honestly, I  will delete my comment to you, because I really have no problem with it, after thinking about it.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @amWhy: fair enough, I've deleted my reply, too.