# What to do when a user is just providing "answer" to a low-quality-question?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I recently came across a lot of such posts where the questioner "just posts" a question without any attempt, without any thoughts, without any source. Just "Question" and with "4 options". Well, there is no problem (since the new user doesn't know anything about asking questions on this site).
But the problem is with those *users who provide the answer in comments*, with a little explanation, (like Option [D] is correct, option [A] is correct, etc.) and the questioner instantly deletes the question after getting the "correct answer".

**My question is,**
Can we do anything with such posts? (Or the user who provided "answer"). I'm aware of [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) but the post is deleted and only users with 10k+ reputation can see it.

Comment: What do you believe *needs* to be done?  Have you read the [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/) announcement?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I've posted it here as I don't know what needs to be done. And Yes, I've read the EoQS announcement. Can't flag deleted posts :|

Comment: I would suspect there is an element of cheating going on in such a situation

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Yes, exactly!

Comment: While it really is frustrating, I am of belief there is nothing you can do. This is an issue beyond the system in a way. **In my opinion**, it would be like asking to change global warming by change of SE policy. I suppose there are auto bans in place if one deletes too many questions, so I won't worry about it too much. The system has only the tools to deal with questions which can be commonly accessed on this site.

Comment: Unfortunately, "preventing cheating" is not part of the mission of Math SE.  To be clear, I don't *want* people to use Math SE to cheat, but preventing cheating is not something which is actionable or enforceable here.  The guidelines regarding context and question quality are, in part, motivated by a desire to prevent cheating; and the EoQS is similar intended to curb bad questions, which often correlate with cheating.  Unfortunately, at the end of the day, Math SE is simply not designed to adjudicate accusations of cheating.

Comment: The best way to respond constructively, @Yooo, is to flag such poor answers for moderator attention (the last in the list of flag reasons, when you click on flags), for consideration of EoQS. (Enforcement of Quality Standards.)  That would be helpful to this site!

Comment: @amWhy The problem is with those users who provide answers in "Comments". *How to flag them?*

Comment: Yooo You can also flag comments, but it would be best to record a few such comment links in one flag, to show a pattern, wrt comments.  A link to any comment is found by right-clicking on the time of comment post, and then clicking "copy link".  I understand that the problem is frustrating, and unfortunately, mods sometimes fail to do anything, even though such comment-answers can violate EoQS.

Comment: E.g., right-clicking on your comment, and selecting "copy link", I'll paste a link to your last comment here:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34879/what-to-do-when-a-user-is-just-providing-answer-to-a-low-quality-question#comment163286_34879  :-)   Thanks for asking!

Comment: @amWhy (Last question) What if such questions are instantly deleted and I don't have comment link? Can it be reported?

Comment: Good question!  I'm hoping @Xander can offer what to do in such cases, for those who cannot see deleted posts.  If you suspect a question, with such a comment-answer that might soon be deleted, try to copy the link to the question before hand.  But none of us can tell the future, and I don't want to drain your time, so I'd prefer a moderator to suggest options. mods seem not to realize the time investment of users that flag. But also, any comment that seems to try to immediately answer any low quality answer, can be flagged (click triangle to the right), by asking a mod to consider EoQS

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a hell of a lot that can be done.  In general, users should not answer questions in the comments, and I try to be responsive to comment flags which indicate that a user *has* answered a question in the comments.  However, once a post has been deleted, a more-or-less desirable outcome has been reached, vis-a-vis site health--the poor question is gone.  If you happen to note that a question is answered in the comments and then deleted, feel free to flag the question, but if you don't have a link anymore, there isn't much that can be done. :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond to newbie answer.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34889/how-to-respond-to-newbie-answer)