# Do we downvote all PSQ? Also a few questions about comment-answers and comment-hints

Tags: discussion, comment, down-votes, voting

At the time of writing, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651141/a-task-from-number-theory) post has 28 views and no downvotes (or upvotes). I see it simply as a PSQ ([Problem Statement Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854)), and it is quite possible it will be closed soon. I didn't downvote it, because I found it a bit interesting. Even added a hint, and am working on it myself. Of course, I won't post a solution, but finding a solution will help me sleep. I didn't upvote it too, since it shows no effort. But I've seen other PSQs attracting downvotes rather quickly (even I downvote the ones which I don't find interesting).  So, do we all refrain from voting on PSQs that seem interesting to us (of course, for many people, this will be very trivial)? I would like an honest answer and not an answer that just describes what ought to be done with PSQs. (Now it has just one upvote and one downvote, so no net change).
Also, I wonder if adding a comment-hint (like I did here) or a comment-answer (I've seen them quite a few times) to PSQs is ethical. Does it violate the quality standards? I often see comment-answers as a way to answer the PSQs question without the risk of downvotes.

Edit: Okay, so I understood a little about the original question. About the side question: Although the comment by Sarvesh talks a bit about answering PSQs in the comments, I'm still not satisfied. Again, do I violate the quality standards if I answer an absolute no-work PSQ (no context even in the comments) in the comments? What about providing a hint in the comments?

According to the question linked by Nij, comment-answers to PSQs should be avoided. What about comment-hints to PSQs?

Comment: I've had some similar experiences. It already has 4 close votes, at the time of typing this comment, so I wouldn't be surprised if it gets closed soon. This isn't an answer to your question, but if you think that question is interesting despite it showing no work, you could post your own version and explain its source.

Comment: @Accelerator I don't have enough rep to see close vote counts. Thanks for adding that. Yeah, I'll try it myself for a long time, and then if I'm unsuccessful, I will post it as a question (with my work) with a link to the original (closed) question

Comment: Voting is anonymous (even to mods) and the motivation for voting is best known to the voter. It is best not to speculate on it.

Comment: I verified that this isn't a duplicate. If you are unable to solve the problem, my best bet in terms of context is to write a computer program and see how far it takes you. Ask a new question, it should be absolutely fine to do so. In fact, I write the code in like 40 seconds and it threw up $3^2+5^1+7^4 = 2415 = 23 \times 105$.

Comment: Any blanket statement "*ALL* PSQs should be downvoted" etc. should be avoided. Apply more nuance in your voting. For example, the question could be a PSQ but there could be a lot of context in the comments. In that situation, we need to take into account the fact that suggested improvements will probably be incorporated, and write a comment "lift your comments to the main post, they are useful context" and so on. Answering PSQs should be a rare affair : there are users who may choose to answer a PSQ using context from comments, before those comments are edited into the main post.

Comment: The question (on main) has been closed, and currently has two delete votes.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer "context in the comments" is not context.  Until it is put into the question itself, it really shouldn't factor into how one votes on the question.  I have even noticed a few people who will put "-1, but if you fix the errors, I'll change my vote".

Comment: @XanderHenderson What is the difference between the same text , provided by the same user (original poster) but being in the comments instead of the main post? Particularly when it turns out to be integral to the question in the end. It was the original poster's comment , but they just didn't appreciate its importance as context so wrote it as a comment. Someone else sees that it's important and writes an answer, because that's enough context for them to see why the question might interest future visitors, and how to answer the question better.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Search engines treat comments differently, someone should not have to read through an extensive back-and-forth to understand a question, and comments can (and often are) deleted, often without notice.  Comments are, *by design*, temporary.  If it isn't in the question itself, it should not be a factor in assessing the quality of the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "Comments are not context" I don't fully subscribe to that. Alternately, I can suggest a compromise : if the OP writes anything in the comments, and a future answerer finds that it *is useful* in answering the question and is an important thing for future visitors to know, then one should be allowed to edit the question and place such a comment as context, or slightly tightened, request the OP via comments to do the same. To me , an OP providing information merely without knowing where to put it can easily be assisted to create a good question, a scalable solution.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Wether or not *you* subscribe to that idea, it is a network-wide understanding of what comments are, and what they are for.  But, yes:  *anyone* can edit the comments into the question.  They should.  Until those comments are edited into the question, they are not "context".

Comment: @XanderHenderson If the compromise works then I'm all for it. Personally, I have not seen much use of the edit function for this purpose, but I have wanted to do it on occasion, refraining to do so only because I haven't been sure how it would be received ( am I "hijacking" the question by editing those comments into the question?) The onus is on the community to see that such an action is acceptable, now that you have mentioned it quite clearly.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer It has been long established that anyone is free to edit a question or answer, as long as it adheres to the intentions of the original author.  If the original author clearly indicated their intentions in the comments, anyone is free to edit those comments into the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you, I can agree with the stance you advocate.

Comment: No idea how *"we"* vote on PSQs, but I will downvote any post I read that has not made a reasonable effort, is not useful, or goes against site policies. PSQs are all of these by definition. Even if it doesn't provide a disincentive to every PSQ post author, it will help them get cleaned up faster if they have a negative scores, versus a neutral score (or god forbid, a positive score, once pity vote makers have come through).

Comment: It depends on how interesting is the problem. If the problem is really interesting for me, I'll upvote the question, If the problem is standard and looks like homework, I'll downvote the question. Otherwise, I will not vote.

Comment: @ryang: answering poor questions even in comments is something against the standards the community has set. Such activity does encourage asking poor questions. Please flag such comments if you notice them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are answers given by comments for low-quality questions against the principles stated with the EoQS?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35117/are-answers-given-by-comments-for-low-quality-questions-against-the-principles-s) tldr **Yes, answers in comments go against (EO)QS, don't use comments that way.**

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Is there any reason why it is viewed negatively to answer poor-quality questions? If the problem itself is interesting--albeit the poster shows little effort--why would a high quality answer be a bad thing? Stackexchange as a whole is visited most frequently via google searches on a specific topic, so providing answers to low-quality questions is still, 99% of the time, a good thing. I also disagree that it would promote low-quality questions as the OP would get downvoted and comments can suggest improvements, while an answer can still stand on it's own.

Comment: @centipede: discouraging such answers in a way discourages askers who ask poor questions. This is in addition to the review mechanism of closing/deleting poor questions.

Comment: @Nij TL;DR what about hints?

Comment: Is it a request for clarification? Is it a suggestion for improvement of the post? That is what comments are for. Is it something else? No, that is not what comments are for.

Comment: Ok thanks @Nij . But, according to this, providing hints in the comments to good questions is not correct, right? I've seen quite a few power users do that. (Even I did just now, sort of)

Comment: Yes, some users ignore policies and systems frequently. There is a lot happening that isn't right, but only so much time to fix it in and energy free for fixing it, when there are much larger issues. You could help be a good example by writing answers *as* Answers, and flagging those hints as not needed.

Comment: If, regardless of the merits of the question, one is not supposed to give hints in comments, and one is certainly not supposed to post hints as answers, then is there any way in which it is acceptable to leave hints?

Comment: @GerryMyerson maybe we can post hints as answers. Is there any policy or something that explicitly stops us from doing that?

Comment: @DS, if you try posting a hint as an answer, someone will tell you it's not an answer, and it should have been posted as a comment(!)

Comment: @GerryMyerson  From a "rules" point of view, it seems that hinting is nowhere acceptable. I can see one use case : there's no context, but a "hint" in the comments is made with the *intent* of having the poster make some *effort, which is then posted as context* for the question. In other words, instead of asking for context, hints are used to make the poster work and use that for context. In that sense, I cannot see anything wrong. Unfortunately (1) It is difficult to if anyone hints with this intent (2) Whether the execution is right (is the hint actually one?)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I confess to having posted several hints with exactly that goal in mind (or to make them actually solve their problem, and hopefully also post an answer). My experience is mixed. More often than not such a hint-in-a-comment has no effect on the asker. This is par for the course, when the asker only wants somebody to do their homework. It does happen that the asker makes an elated "Got it!"-reply (frequently enough to keep me going). However, it is admittedly rare that the asker proceeds to post a full answer. May be somebody else has a better track record than I do?

Comment: I'm inclined to answer in comment if I'm not sure what is really asked by OP. It is sort of alternative to asking OP what he asks. If I guessed correctly I can repost my answer in answer format, if not (which happen more frequently) I can just delete the comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "...if you try posting a hint as an answer, someone will tell you it's not an answer, and it should have been posted as a comment(!)"  The discussion about whether or not hints are okay is long, and I don't think that I have seen any clear consensus come from the community.  When I was new to the site, [I tried to get clarity on the issue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28969/).  The most upvoted answer seems to presuppose that the question itself is asking for hints, and asserts that, in that situation, hints in the answers are good.

Comment: The [next most upvoted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28973/) puts a lot of effort into defining what a hint is, and ultimately concludes that hints are okay in the answers, as long as the hint is known by the answerer to lead directly to a complete solution (more or less).  So leaving hints in the answers is *possibly* acceptable, per the community standards.

Comment: On the other hand, hinting in the comments is, per SE rules, not allowed:  comments (on the main site) are for suggestions and clarification, only.  My primary objective in moderation (with respect to these kinds of comments) is to maintain or improve the overall quality of the material on this site.  If a question is of very low quality, I would prefer that it not be addressed until it is improved.  No hints, no answers---fix the question **first**.  However, *if* one is compelled to engage with a poor-quality question, I, personally, would rather that hints be left in the comments.

Comment: Answered questions are harder to delete than unanswered questions, hence I would prefer that folk not post answers to those questions.  While it still isn't really okay to post a hint in the comments, if the question is destined for closure, it would be less bad to post a hint in the comments than to post a hint as an answer.

Comment: To answer the question posted here, I do downvote and vote to close a lot of questions on MSE. I often write in the comments that we are not here to do anyone's homework, and their question does not meet the MSE Guidelines. It's probably unpleasant for the person who posted the question to read, but that is the point! If someone just posts their math homework on here expecting someone else to do it for them, then they *should* feel bad! Often, either the person steps up and edits the question, or the question ends up getting deleted by the person asking. A win for the forum either way!

Comment: I think giving helpful hints to bad questions in the comments is very bad for the site, and it probably goes against MSE Guidelines. It is ultimately encouraging more bad questions as the people posting them are getting a lot of what they wanted.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Mike. Unfortunately, a significant subset of the community is either unaware of or disagrees with Paramanand's above advisory: for example, under a borderline acceptable Question recently, a user was insisting that their Comment-answer was apt while an actual Answer wasn't, while electing that the Question was not close-worthy. Under a separate Question, another user said that they were posting a Comment-answer to avoid being censured for Answering a PSQ. And of course, there's an army of users who regularly Comment-answer (or provide hints in the comments to) PSQs.